# What is the resultant force acting on a body when two equal and opposite forces act on it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statics

I feel I am missing a key intuitive insight into understanding a problem like as follows:

[image]

(Sorry for rough drawing) The system above consists of a hammer, floor, and a ball in between those two. When the hammer strikes the ball with F_h, there is an equal and opposite normal reaction F_n.

What would be the resultant force or the force experienced by the ball?

For context:
This intuitive discord I'm feeling comes originally from this problem:
[image]

^ We are asked to find the "Gripping force at B in terms of the applied force F"

Comment: 2 opposite and equal forces cancel each other out so there is no net force

Comment: Would that be the same for the pliers problem asking for the grip force at B?

Comment: the normal force on each side would give B no acceleration, only static friction to hold B. You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force#Equilibrium

Comment: as for the hammer and normal force, there is no acceleration, only mechanical stress. Read the third paragraph at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force